# Sharing variables in Tensorflow, how to share conv2d()?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to access once created variable(or Tensor and variable altoghter, not sure yet about separation of those definitions in TF) in following way:

```
def C2d(Tensor, params):
    with tf.variable_scope("conv"):
        Tensor = tf.pad(Tensor, params)
        conv = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(Tensor, params)
    return conv

with tf.variable_scope('scope1'):
    var1 = C2d(Tensor, params)

with tf.variable_scope('scope1', reuse=True):
    var2 = C2d(Tensor, params)
```

and

```
print(var1 == var2)
```

prints `False`

`var1:` `<tf.Tensor 'scope1/conv/Conv/Relu:0' shape=(475, 473, 256) dtype=float32>`

```
var2:  <tf.Tensor 'scope1_1/conv/Conv/Relu:0' shape=(475, 473, 256) dtype=float32>
```

How do I get same Tensor with such function call?

2. And follow-up question, `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(...)` takes as a parameter `weigth_initializer`, if I am trying to get a reference by variable to an existing tensor that already has it's initialization, what happens when I pass this parameter initializer second time?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the functioning seems correct to me, `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d()` returns the output of the layer, and it is normal that it returns different outputs when you call it two times.

If you check the variables created in your graph, for instance with `tf.global_variables()`, you will see that it has created only one copy of the variables initiated by the layer.

For the second question, you can pass the same variable initializer to many variables, so it should not conflict.

Comment: Yes you are right, there is only one copy of weights. Not really transparent behavior though... Does different name of the Tensor in this case means that graph that leads to this Tensor or at least this Tensor itself gets computed two times? If will be a waste of computational resourses and I think it's better to store this Tensor in a global dictionary.

Comment: Calling `con2d()` two times means that you need two different dataflows, but that the operations there in should use the same variables. For instance, you might have images with two different dimensions that you want to process with the same convolutional weights.

Comment: Then you create 2 placeholders `p1, p2` (one for each dimension) and create the 2 parts of the graph calling `t1 = conv2d(p1), t2 = conv2d(p2)` (the second time with `reuse=True`), so that when you run `t1` you execute the graph for the first image, and running `t2` you run the second image

Comment: I mean if I want to pass output of conv2d to the 2 different layers, what is the right way to do so?

Comment: I don't understand precisely what you mean... each time you call `conv2d()`, a new tensor is created. This tensor is some operation done on the input tensor. Usually, it does not make much sense to call it two times on the same input, since exact copies of the same tensor are created, and there should be no need for it, but it does make sense to call `conv2d()` with the same parameters (hence the same variable scope with reuse=True) but on different input tensors

Comment: What is created only once are the weights and biases the construction of the output tensor depends on. These are not returned from the function, and you might access to them in many ways, for instance using `tf.get_variable` or by cycling over the `tf.global_variables()` and filtering by the name